# Android - LocationListener cant define "this" on methods

Tags: android, this, locationlistener

Im creating an app to show users location on a map. The problem is that when calling the methods requestLocationUpdates, or removeUpdates, i get an error in the LocationListener parameter. I know this may be due to importing the wrong files, but i did import the com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener one.
I did my research but really cant find the solution to this. I´ll put some of my code so it may help.
Thanks you for your help.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener {



    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,400,1,this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng cali = new LatLng(3.451234, -76.532694);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cali));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Double lat = location.getAltitude();
        Double lng = location.getLongitude();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }




}
```

As i told up the problem here are in the lines:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,400,1,this);
```

And

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

BTW if i remove those 2 lines and just work on showing a map and markers, the code works with no problem.

Comment: replace "this" with "getApplicationContext()"

Comment: Thanks for your response, i did as you said, but got the same error.
locationManager.removeUpdates(getApplicationContext());
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,400,1,getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ,following line

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

With

```
import android.location.LocationListener ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i did change it, it asked me to add some other methods and now i think is working, it still shows the redunderline but now is about permissions, suggesting me to add permission check.

Comment: Ok ,Good , Simply add the permissions in the Androidmanifest file .

Comment: If my answer solved the problem you posted above , then you can mark above answer as accepted .

Comment: i did, but as my reputation is 1, you get the point but publicy score is not